# Python pywinauto PuTTy how to wait till the task is over

Tags: python, putty, pywinauto

I use Application from pywinauto.application
After logging in i want it to execute commads like :

```
    putty.type_keys("ls")
    putty.type_keys("{ENTER}")
```

To execute next command i need to wait for this one to end. Instead of typing something like :

```
    time.sleep(5)
```

I need the program to know when the command is done and ready for next command, not to wait X seconds and hope the running task will be over untill that(for example downloadign a file). I looked up into "wait()", but didn't find anything useful. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need pywinauto for executing console commands by ssh! Just do something like this:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(“ssh user:password@hostname ls -l /home”)
for line in output.split(“\n”):
    subpath = “ “.join(line.split(“ “)[1:])
    print(subpath)
```